# How to pull deeply nested data from a dictionary in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to print nested data from an ansible dictionary. However, I cannot figure out how to pull the nested values.  Specifically, in the data below, I am trying to print the two values returned under "ipv4".   Currently, the output of item.value.ipv4 is the portion in brackets below:

```
"msg": "GigabitEthernet0/0/0,[{'address': '192.168.3.1', 'subnet': '28'}]"
```

I would like to just use the value like so:

```
"msg": "GigabitEthernet0/0/0, 192.168.3.1, 28"
```

I cannot figure out how to pull this nested data out of to do this.  To put it simply, it would be nice if something like this worked: item.value.ipv4['address']. How is this done?

```
  tasks:

    - name: get config for Cisco IOS
      ios_facts:
        gather_subset: all
        gather_network_resources: interfaces

   - name: create dictionary with ansible_net_interfaces
      set_fact:
        foo_value: "{{ query('dict', ansible_net_interfaces) }}"

    - name: display the results of foo_value
      debug:
        msg: "{{ foo_value }}"

    - name: display certain detalys values from foo_value
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }},{{ item.value.ipv4 }}"
      with_items: "{{ foo_value }}"
```

These tasks produce the following:

```
TASK [display the results of foo] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.3.1] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "key": "GigabitEthernet0/0/0",
            "value": {
                "bandwidth": 1000000,
                "description": "This is an interface description",
                "duplex": "Full",
                "ipv4": [
                    {
                        "address": "192.168.3.1",
                        "subnet": "28"
                    }
                ],
                "lineprotocol": "up",
                "macaddress": "50f7.123c.b0c0",
                "mediatype": "RJ45",
                "mtu": 1500,
                "operstatus": "up",
                "type": "ISR4331-3x1GE"
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "GigabitEthernet0/0/1",
            "value": {
                "bandwidth": 1000000,
                "description": "This is another interface description",
                "duplex": "Full",
                "ipv4": [
                    {
                        "address": "192.168.3.33",
                        "subnet": "30"
                    }
                ],
                "lineprotocol": "up",
                "macaddress": "50f7.123c.b0c0",
                "mediatype": "RJ45",
                "mtu": 1500,
                "operstatus": "up",
                "type": "ISR4331-3x1GE"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipv4` is a list of dictionaries. Assuming you need only the first dictionary,

```
    - name: display certain detalys values from foo_value
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }},{{ item.value.ipv4[0].address }},{{ item.value.ipv4[0].subnet }}"
      when: item.value.ipv4 is defined and item.value.ipv4[0].subnet is defined and item.value.ipv4[0].address is defined 
      with_items: "{{ foo_value }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did get one error where this data did not exist in one of the dictionaries.  It produced:

"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element"   Is there a way to set 'only if it exists'?

Comment: Can you say which element is missing?

Comment: Yes, specifically, there are cases where either item.value.ipv4 will be missing or item.value.ipv4[0].address or item.value.ipv4[0].subnet.

Comment: Updated the answer with `when` conditional, see if it works.

Comment: Very nice.  That works perfectly - I searched quite a lot for the correct syntax for this, and couldn't find it. Thank you for the help.